# How can I parametrize two tikz circles to fit tufte marginpar?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tufte, circles

Ho can I parametrize the circles to fit the tufte marginpar? I want to able to change the sovrapposition of the circles (possibly in ratio from 0 to 1) and get an adjusted `\diameter` to fit `\marginparwidth` automatically.

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\newcommand{\panning}{1}

\newlength{\diameter}
\setlength{\diameter}{.34\marginparwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{marginfigure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5]
                    \draw (90:\panning) circle (\diameter);
                    \draw (210:\panning) circle (\diameter);
                    \draw (330:\panning) circle (\diameter);
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This is a margin figure.}
    \end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not work on an updated TeXlive 2014.

Comment: @Sigur sorry, fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple calculation shows that the radius (you called it diameter) has to be `1/2(\marginparwidth-\sqrt{3}\padding)`, so

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\newcommand\panning{0.5}
\newlength\diameter
\pgfmathsetlength{\diameter}{0.5*\marginparwidth-0.5*sqrt(3)*\panning cm}    

\begin{document}
    \begin{marginfigure}\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5]
                    \draw (90:\panning) circle (\diameter);
                    \draw (210:\panning) circle (\diameter);
                    \draw (330:\panning) circle (\diameter);
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This is a margin figure.}
    \end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: +1 Good answer, Medina. You can even load only `pgfplots` without the complete `tikz` package.